# Powershell SQL Insert with parameters getting error

Tags: sql, .net, powershell

I'm trying to create a parameterized insert statement in my PS script and I keep getting an error about converting nvarchar:

**Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '(select e.endpointid from endpoints e inner join meters m on m.meterid=e.meterid where m.meterno ='06700' )' to data type int.".**

Here's the relevant part of my script:

```
 $linesplit = $line -split ","
 $prefix = "$($linesplit[0]),$($linesplit[1]),$($linesplit[2]),$($linesplit[3])"
 $numberOfMeters = $linesplit.length - 4 
 for($i = 1; $i -le $numberOfMeters; $i++){
     $meternumber = $linesplit[3 + $i]
     $meternumber = "'"+$meternumber+"'"
     $notecontent = "'"+$prefix+"'"
     $endpointid = "(select e.endpointid from endpoints e inner join meters m on m.meterid=e.meterid where m.meterno ="+$meternumber+" )"
                     write-host $endpointid -fore Cyan
     $userid = "55"
     $created = "(select GETDATE())"
     $notetype = "0"
     $note = $notecontent
         write-host $note -fore Cyan
     $sqlinsert = "
         insert into endpointnotes (endpointId, userId, created, noteType, note)
         VALUES (@endpointid,@userid,@created,@notetype,@note)
         "

         # Connect to SQL database and run insert statement
         $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
         $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=$Server;database=$CSDatabase;uid=;pwd="
         $SqlConnection.open()
         $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
         $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@endpointid", $endpointid)
         $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", $userid)
         $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@created", $created)
         $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@notetype", $notetype)
         $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@note", $note)
         $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlinsert
         $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
         $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
         $SqlConnection.close()
         }
```

Is it even possible to use a SELECT statement in one of my parameters?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to use a select statement as a parameter value. You will need to rewrite the insert as an `INSERT ... FROM` with a `CROSS APPLY` for the `endpointId`, or find the `endpointId` first and pass it through.

Comment: "CROSS APPLY"? hadn't encountered that before, but I'll read up on it.  I might just run a select query first to get the endpointid into a PS variable first and then pass it in as a parameter.  Thanks!

Comment: @JayCee: Outer apply should do your work I believe, or even cross apply. :
[CROSS Apply & OUTER Apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

Comment: remove the quote's from the meters in the query  where m.meterno ='06700' )  <--  Those quotes. its a int sql column, thus requires you not to use the quotes which define a string. (nvarchar)